# scrollcontroller not attached to any scroll views (Swiper)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I'm using a `Swiper` package to achieve a carousel effect on my images.
I'm trying to update the current index of my `Swiper` by passing a `callback` function to it's child.

but when I try to call the function, it returns this " `scrollcontroller not attached` " error.

I've added a `SwiperController` but still the same.

Here is my code:

```
SwiperController swiperController;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        color: Colors.black,
        child: Swiper(
          controller: swiperController,
          index: _index,
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext c, int i) {
            return StoriesPerUser(
              storiesList: widget.storiesList,
              selectedIndex: i,
              updateFunction: callBack,
            );
          },
          itemCount: widget.storiesList.length,
          loop: false,
          duration: 1000,
        ));
  }

  callBack() {
    setState(() {
     _index++; 
    });
  }

Please help.
```

Answer (score 2):

**ANSWER**:

If any of you guys want to use this package, and if you want a feature similar to mine, instead of updating the index, just use the one of the methods of `SwiperController` which is `next()`.

this solved my problem:

```
callBack() {
    setState(() {
      swiperController.next();
    });
  }
```

Comment: Good job on solving this issue!

Comment: super tidy solution

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

It seems that SwiperController was not instantiated and initialised. You can do it by overriding the initState method:

```
@override
void initState() {
  controller = SwiperController();
  controller.length = 10
  //controller.fillRange(0, 10, SwiperController());
  super.initState();
}
```

Comment: Hi! I've seen similar problems but unfortunately `SwiperController` doesn't have that `initialScrollOffset`

Comment: may I ask where did that `autoplayes` came from?

Comment: It gives a lot of error. Thanks for your time. I think the swipecontroller should't be treated as somewhat similar to scrollcontroller

Comment: Sorry, I found an example here: https://github.com/best-flutter/flutter_swiper/blob/master/example/lib/InnerSwiper.dart . I think you only need to instantiate controller. Will update the answer.

Comment: yes I've looked into this too but changed my logic because I needed to implement the skip, pause, resume logics. basically I'm trying to create a similar flow to facebook's stories & instagram's.

Comment: Hey bro `.length` isn't available in swipercontroller. but thanks for trying to help!